# Guide to set up a VPN on Ubuntu 17.10 with Private Internet Access?

Tags: networking, vpn, 17.10, pptp

I just subscribed to a VPN connection service "Private Internet Access" (https://www.privateinternetaccess.com) and would like to use the built in Ubuntu 17.10 VPN connection options and not download the PIA manager to connect.

What information do I need to have in order to set up a VPN connection?

Why would a VPN service want me to install an additional program to connect?

Currently the PIA Manager does not work with Ubuntu 17.04 and 17.10 (https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/comment/46908/#Comment_46908) but surely the built in VPN provider in Ubuntu could be configured to connect?

Any help with this appreciated!

Comment: What type of VPN service is it? Are the necessary additions for network-manager installed to support that type of VPN? Do you have all the necessary configuration information to properly configure the VPN? There's not enough information in your question to know exactly how to configure the specific VPN you wish to use.

Comment: Hi @dobey, I'm currently using https://www.privateinternetaccess.com to start my VPN connection, but I have no idea how to set up a VPN. I don't even know what information I need to set up a VPN, so any information is helpful. My VPN provider has given me an account and I can generate PPTP login details, but I have no idea what else I need to start the VPN. If someone knows the Ubuntu 17.10 system they might be able to tell me what information I need to set up a VPN connection (the website is trying to get me to download an additional program for Ubuntu, something I wish to avoid if I can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [client support](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/) page for PIA has setup guides for alternate configurations at the bottom of the page. I would suggest using the [OpenVPN instructions](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/ubuntu-openvpn), as it should be a bit more secure than using PPTP. You may also need to install the `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` package, though.

Comment: Aha so PPTP is not encrypted! I wasn't aware of that. So OpenVPN is a good alternative? Thanks for the advice!